# There may be a syntax error in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp, host

Error while installing WAMP. Orange Icon. Icon error says that ERROR APACHE VARIABLES

```
Sorry,

There is an error.

Unable to find the Apache variables.
There may be a syntax error in httpd.conf.
To be checked by the tool integrated in Wampserver:
Right-click -> Tools -> Check httpd.conf syntax.


Press ENTER to continue...
```

This is what shows in Command Prompt. Any Help?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and pick the appropriate other stackexchange site. But with all the detail you include, I'd first look at line 42

Answer (score 0):

If you edited DocumentROOT and Directory in the httpd-vhosts.conf file, then it may occur. It happened to me when I used backslash in the path. After using forward slash in place of them, it worked fine for me